# Entropy of a state subject to the action of a set of random unitaries

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

Suppose that we have a known set of unitaries $U_1,...,U_n$ randomly selected from the Haar measure and suppose that each unitary is applied with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ to some input state $\rho$ which is pure and lives in a $d$-dimensional Hilbert space.

For $n\rightarrow\infty$ it is clear that:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}H(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nU_i\rho U_i^+)=\log d
\end{equation}
where $H$ is the [von Neumann entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy).

However, for small $n$ how would you explicitly compute the entropy of the state? I'll plug some numbers to show an example: if we let $n=2$, $d=2$, this would be equivalent to computing the following average:
\begin{equation}
E_U\left[H\left(\frac{1}{2} U_1|0\rangle\langle0|U_1^++\frac{1}{2}U_2|0\rangle\langle0|U_2^+\right)\right]
\end{equation}
I've written $|0\rangle\langle0|$ since by symmetry any pure state will have the same entropy, the average is outside the entropy function because by hypothesis the set of unitaries are known, which means that we can distinguish between each set of unitaries, even if we don't know which unitary from the set has been applied.

Comment: Are you trying to find a general formula for the entropy that is independent of the unitaries $U_i$ and the state $\rho$?

Comment: Well, rather than a relation independent of the $U_i$, the formula I'm trying to compute would be the average over all unitaries, which by symmetry should be identical for all input pure states.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, maybe my question was not clear enough, I updated accordingly.

Comment: Still confused about the extra averaging after calculating the entropy. If you have a given set of known unitaries, then the correct entropy is $H(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} U_i \rho U^+_i)$, no further averaging is needed. Averaging would only make sense if there are many different *sets* of randomly selected unitaries, and you don't know which set has been applied to your state $\rho$.

Comment: So I agree with you that averaging inside the entropy makes sense if we don't know which set is being applied. But since the set is randomly drawn, even though we know which set is being applied the "relevant" quantity is the average entropy.

Comment: No, I am saying that averaging **outside** the entropy only makes sense if there are many different sets, and we don't know which set is applied. Ando, please can you clarify: is there a **single** given set of randomly drawn unitaries, or is your procedure repeated? I ask because the problem, as stated, is trivially solvable because the unitaries are *known*: the answer is $H(\sum_{i=1}^N U_i \rho U_i^+)$ which depends strongly on the unitaries $U_i$ and the state $\rho$. The problem is more interesting if you want to calculate the average entropy over *many repetitions* of your procedure.

Comment: The procedure is repeated many times, each time the set of unitaries is known, what is unknown is which of the unitaries from a given set is applied.

Comment: See the answer below. Please let me know if I have understood your problem correctly.

Comment: What does $E_U$ denote?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch $E_U$ is just the average over all the possible sets of unitaries.

Comment: One can try to do it brute force -- for $n=2$, $d=2$ I get an average entropy of $0.5$. (If you're interested I can post how to do it in that case.) I'm not sure how far one can push this. Which values of $n$ and $d$ are you interested in?

Comment: In fact, that would completely address my question, the $n=2,d=2$ case would do it. My goal (well beyond the question) is to non-naively lower bound the average entropy for $d=2$ as a function of $n$ but first I'm trying to understand the basic case.

Comment: I now posted a solution for $n=2$, $d=2$. Let me know if this is what you were looking for. BTW, for $d=2$ one might be able to push this further (by nesting several integrals over Haar-random states): For $n=3$, the entropy for each mixture can still be computed exactly, and numerical integration gives an avg. entropy of about 0.580211.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution for $n=2$, $d=2$:

You are trying to compute the average entropy of
$$
\rho(U_1,U_2) = U_1|0\rangle\langle0|U_1^\dagger + U_2|0\rangle\langle0|U_2^\dagger
$$
with $U_1$ and $U_2$ distributed according to the Haar measure.
This is equal to the entropy of 
$$
\rho'(U) = |0\rangle\langle0| + U|0\rangle\langle0|U^\dagger
$$
where $U=U_1^\dagger U_2$, which is of course still distributed according to the Haar measure. In turn, this is
$$
\tilde\rho(|\psi\rangle)= |0\rangle\langle0| + |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|
$$
with $|\psi\rangle$ a Haar-random qubit state.

We know that a Haar-random qubit state can be parametrized as 
$$
|\psi\rangle = \cos\tfrac\theta2 \,|0\rangle + e^{i\phi}\sin\tfrac\theta2\, |1\rangle\ ,
$$
where one needs to integrate in spherical coordinates (i.e., with a measure $\tfrac1{4\pi}\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi$, $\theta\in[0,\pi]$, $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$).

We now have 
$$\tilde\rho(|\psi\rangle) = \frac12 
\left(\begin{matrix}1+\cos^2\tfrac\theta2 & e^{i\phi}\sin\tfrac\theta2\,\cos\tfrac\theta2\\
e^{-i\phi}\sin\tfrac\theta2\,\cos\tfrac\theta2 & \sin^2\tfrac\theta2\end{matrix}\right)\ .
$$
The entropy of this state is independent of $\phi$ (so we set $\phi=0$), and then we can easily check (e.g. using Mathematica) that the von Neumann entropy (defined with the logarithm base $2$) is
$$
H(\tilde\rho) = \tfrac12\left[-\cos^2\tfrac\theta4\log_2\cos^2\tfrac\theta4 +
\sin^2\tfrac\theta4\log_2\sin^2\tfrac\theta4\right]\ .
$$
The Haar-average can then again be evaluated with Mathematica and turns out to be
$$
\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\phi
\int_0^\pi\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\, H(\tilde\rho) = \frac13+\frac{1}{6\ln 2} \approx 0.5738 \ .
$$

Comment: Yes, this is perfect, really thanks a lot! There is one thing that I didn't follow, shouldn't $|\psi\rangle=\cos\frac{\theta}{2}|0\rangle+e^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta }{2}|1 \rangle $? In that case, following your answer, I get that the average is $0.3977$

Comment: Ups, that's true. Thanks. I've corrected it (and also expressed the entropy with the logarithm base 2).

Answer (score 2):

Let me restate the problem in a more operational way, assuming that I have understood the OP's comments below the question. The key point is that the answer depends both on $n$ **and** on the number of times that the described procedure is repeated.

Alice prepares $M$ identical systems in different states, denoted $\rho_{\mu}$. Each state $\rho_{\mu}$ is prepared by selecting a set of $n$ unitaries $\{U^{(\mu)}_i\}$ randomly according to the Haar measure, and applying one of them to some fixed initial state $\rho$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$. Alice then picks one of the $M$ systems at random and sends it to Bob, along with the list of unitaries $\{U^{(\mu)}_i\}$ used in the preparation of each system. Bob, however, does not know which set of unitaries was used to prepare the specific system that he receives.

The state assigned by Bob is
\begin{align*}
\rho_B & = \frac{1}{M} \sum\limits_{\mu=1}^M \,\rho_{\mu} \\
& = \frac{1}{M} \sum\limits_{\mu=1}^M \, \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\, U^{(\mu)}_i \rho \,U^{(\mu) \dagger}_i\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{nM} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{nM}\, U_k \,\rho\, U_k^{\dagger},
\end{align*}
where $U_k = U^{(\mu)}_i$ with $k = i + (\mu -1)n$. Since each set of unitaries $\{U^{(\mu)}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is uniformly distributed, so is the entire set of unitaries $\{U_k\}_{k=1}^{nM}$. The problem thus reduces to a single realisation of the procedure for each state $\rho_{\mu}$, but now with $M \times n$ unitaries in total. The correct entropy for Bob to ascribe is simply $H(\rho_B)$, with $\rho_B$ given above.

The intuition here is that from Bob's point of view, the way in which Alice grouped the unitaries is not important. In reality only one unitary from the set was applied to the system that he receives, and each unitary has equal probability $\frac{1}{nM}$.

In general the result thus depends on the set of unitaries and their relation to the initial state. The problem simplifies in the limit of many repetitions $M\to \infty$, in which we have
$$\rho_B = \lim_{M\to\infty} \frac{1}{nM} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{nM}\, U_k \,\rho\, U_k^{\dagger} = \int \mathrm{d}U\, U\rho U^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{d} 1_d,$$
and the entropy is just $H(\rho_B) = \log d$. Note that in this limit, the answer is *independent* of $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the insight I think your operational interpretation is correct. However it doesn't address completely my question, the thing is that Bob knows the set of unitaries in every realization, which means that if $n$ is small $\rho_B$ is not the maximally mixed state.

Comment: Aha so I didn't understand your question then, sorry. The problem is indeed different if Bob knows the unitaries for each set. I'll think about it!